# How can i return multiple rows from stored procedure in Maria DB?

Tags: mariadb

I want to return multiple records from table on dynamic conditions through a stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Each `SELECT` delivers one "result set" of any number of "rows".  The calling code must have a loop to grab the resultsets.  Within that, parse the rows just as you would for an ordinary `SELECT`.

The details depend on the language you are using.

Comment: Thanks Rick for your answer,I am using Java Language,  but what my concern is that when i use two SELECT statement inside a procedure, what it does is .. it only return the first resultset , so if possible can you please tell me how can i return multiple resultsets?

Comment: A quick web search found http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html which talks about "dynamic result sets".  (I'm not a Java programmer.)